# How can I populate with mongoose the following code?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code for the models

```
// rooms model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('rooms', {
  type_id: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'types',
    required: true,
  },
  number: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

// types model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Model
module.exports = mongoose.model('types', {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  people: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },

  images: [String],
  details: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});
```

For the get request, I have.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);
  Rooms.find(req.query)
    .populate({ path: 'types', select: 'name price people images details' })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

I am trying to populate to achieve the following results as the room with its type as name price people image details, unfortunately, I only get the following. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e88e3107f10f555cffc36c9",
        "type_id": "5e88cb8360363053b67c3f85",
        "number": 103,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: `types` is not a path in the `Rooms` model. What are you trying to populate?

Comment: You might need to to change your `.populate({ path: 'types',...` to `.populate({ path: 'type_id',...`. As @ZachB is menioning, you don't have a field called `types` in your model `rooms`.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back you guys pointed out the fix.